# How to get $_GET variables in PHP

Tags: php, register-globals

I'm working on application built years ago, that has recently stopped working correctly. Old programmer said, that he might be accessing `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables without reading them from `$_GET[] array`, but through the `register_globals`

I want to ask: What are different ways to access `$_GET` variables without using `$_GET[]` array (e.g. direct ways?) and, if known, how can I check if this application uses any of them?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**: The other ways I remembered was `register_globals`, not `magic_quotes`. Also, I do not wish to **use it**, but rather detect if it was used and in latest server update deprecated (what *could* explain why app stopped working correctly)

**EDIT**: My english is horrible today. As I explained in one of answers: **I need to check, whether original programmer used some obscure and/or deprecated method of getting variables from query string to PHP, so the values application now works with are wrong/not initialized**

**IMPORTANT EDIT**: `import_request_variables` is off the table, it isn't used. All `$_` arrays are off the table too, because latest update wouldn't broke them (=>they still work). How can I detect what variables are initialized with `register_globals`?

**YET ANOTHER EDIT**: I found this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
  eval("\$".$k." = '".$v."';");
}
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
  eval("\$".$k." = '".$v."';");
}
```

Could it have been broken by one of *latest* updates (max. 1 week ago)?

Comment: Does it give some kind of an error? If not, what about it isn't working. We need to know that before we can diagnose the problem.

Comment: I would also think he rather meant `register_globals` or the PHP3 arrays `$HTTP_GET_VARS` instead. Either way not good. Takes effort to rewrite such things.

Comment: @Dave and Adam sitting in a tree... ;)

Comment: @Dave: ^_^ @Nathan - I don't understand completely what's different, I've been called just few days ago to look at it, but project manager says that values are not correct. That's all I know, PHP looks it works okay...

Comment: @Adam Kiss and YET ANOTHER EDIT: Seems like a selfmade `register_globals`. It should better be done without eval. This could be done using `$$k = $v;`, but you should try refactoring this.

Comment: @Adam Kiss Wow, you should post that code on [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) sound like a solid candidate to me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean through [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) and not [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)... BTW Register Globals is pure evil **never** use them (and they are deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0)!

**Edit:** If you want to check if the application used Register Globals, try to search for `$_GET` values as variables. For example for `index.php?id=123` try to look for `$id` in the PHP code. If you find it this does not mean that the script uses Register Globals but if `$id` comes from nowhere and is never initialized/setted it's a good (bad!) sign that the app uses Register Globals...

Comment: @Christopher W. Allen-Poole Register Globals are totally useless to any real programmer. They are the biggest WTF of the history of PHP. I guess they were made to help non-programmers tp build apps with security holes in them ;)

Comment: Well I don't use them and never had - I remember first thing I read in some PHP book years ago - **don't use `register_globals`**, so I never cared about it. Maybe I should have.

Comment: @AlexV That's more or less my opinion.  I mean, I guess you could encapsulate everything in functions and ini files, but it still seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You also have [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), [magic_quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php) (deprecated) would only influence the content of the variables, not the means of capturing them.

Also see [import_request_variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php), the original coder may have used it to grab the contents of a GET variable and insert it into another variable which is then subsequently being referenced.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` will give you the raw GET string.

That said, this sounds like a problem that should be fixed at its root, not by using a different variable.

If magic quotes are an issue, do a check for whether they are enabled, and deal with the incoming data accordingly.

The [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) page in the PHP manual shows a way to "fix" the incoming data depending on whether the functionality is activated or not. It's not very efficient for huge amounts of data, but should do in an everyday task.

Comment: The question was bad worded (I'm really tired today ^_^) - I need to check, whether original programmer used some obscure and/or deprecated method of getting variables from query string to PHP.

Comment: @Adam now that register_globals is on the table, my answer probably doesn't apply. Never mind. Still, the basic suggestion of fixing the root cause is still valid :) Although it could be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably [PHP's `register_globals`](http://php.net/register_globals). This option makes `$_GET['some_var']` or their equivalent `$_POST` version available as `$some_var` automatically. This is deprecated and you should definitely not use it, but the other programmer might have used them in that application.

Answer (score 1):

Register Globals is a horrible feature that older PHP programs often rely on.

With register globals switched on, PHP will look at the GET and POST variables and "promote" them to normal variable names - eg `$_GET['myvar']` would be accessible in the code as `$myvar`.

Among other issues, this makes the program very easy for hackers to break simply by guessing what other variable names the programmer may have used. The register globals feature has therefore been turned off by default for a long time, is now officially deprecated, and will be removed entirely in a future version.

Because the variables used this way are referenced in a way that is indistinguishable from normal variables, it means that trying to update old code that uses register globals can be very difficult. It does depend a lot on how well written the code is.